# React map key value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping

I want to map an object's key name and their values from an API into a list.

[image]

I need the output to be

```
Country: AE
    Buy:   
      1) Provider name: Google Play Movies
Country: AU
    Rent:
      1) Provider name: ...
      ...
      7) ...
    Buy:
      and so on
```

I'm storing the object's name as `stream`

```
const Stream = ({ stream }) => {

    console.log(stream)

    return (
        <div>
            {stream?.results?.map((eachItem) => (
                <li>{eachItem.link}</li>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Stream
```

I tried mapping atleast the link but I'm getting errors.

```
Uncaught TypeError: _stream$results.map is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can only map through an array. You are mapping through stream.results which appears to be an object. You need to use another option to loop through the objects properties to get to the values.
There is a few ways you can achieve this and what is going to be best will be dependant on your scenario and exactly how you want to display the data.

for in loop, Object.keys(yourobject), Object.entries(yourobject) and Object.values(yourobject) are all options for getting into objects and extracting specific data. You need one or a combination of those to get your information.Play around with those in the console and read up about them on MDN
If you get to an actual array, you can map that.. ex rent and buy can be mapped.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to `map` an object while the function is intended for Arrays. To get around that, create an array of your object keys and map over them.

```
return (
    <div>
        {Object.keys(results).map(key => (
            <li>{results[key].link}</li>
        )}
    </div>
)
```